# Angular - how do I keep from rendering template until an event fires?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that looks something like the code below.  It works fine, but I have had to resort to creating inline template code since I don't want the template to render until the click event has fired.  But it would be cleaner if I could assign the directive template and delay rendering until the event has fired.

Is there a way to do this?

```
(function() {
  app.directive("nodeTabset", function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: '&',
      controller: [
        '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$compile', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
          var TABS;

          // Ad hoc template
          TABS = "<div id='node-tabset-wrapper'>\n  <div id='node-tabset'>\n    <div>Set Attribute</div>\n    <div ng-show='node.name == \"a\"'>Set Scrape Job</div>\n  </div>\n  <div id='node-tabset-corner'></div>\n</div>";

          $scope.selectNode = function(node) {
            node.addClass("selected");
            node.prepend(TABS);
            $compile(node.children()[0])($scope);
            return $scope.$apply();
          };
          return $scope.evaluateSelection = function($event) {
            var parent, 
            parent = angular.element($event.currentTarget).parent();

            // do some stuff
             return $scope.selectNode(parent);
          };
        }
      ],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        return element.bind('click', scope.evaluateSelection);
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have look at the promise library 
[$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if`. It will remove the element until the expression is true and create it, new scope and all. Bind your click to change a bool to true and set that bool in the ng-if.